# Can I stop emitting from Reduce function?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am writing a MapReduce code for MongoDB (in Javascript obviously). In the reduce code, it looks like I have to return some value (which is the same as emitting) always? I couldn't find a way not to but if I can stop emitting a record in the reduce function, my code can be simpler so I am wondering.

Answer (score 0):

I believe emitting is completely optional (and incidentally "returning" a value in your map shouldn't do anything). Just don't emit inside of your mapping function and the result won't make it to the reducing function

Comment: David, my question is from reduce function, not from map function.

Comment: @kee Ah interesting. Could you post a simplified sample of what you're working with?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand where you are coming from.

The fundamentals of MR is that of a Map Reduce. If your MR has no reduce function is has no output. As such a reduce function is always expected.

It is true that if you are emitting one row from your map function then reduce does not need to run. However for a MR to fully run it does have to call a reduce function otherwise there is no output which makes the MR pointless.

> In the reduce code, it looks like I have to return some value (which is the same as emitting) always?

Yes this is because of how MR works mathematically: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Amoretechnicalexplanation you can see a basic explanation of it there. MongoDB expects to run it like this as such it only supports this method.

Comment: Probably it wasn't clear but I am not saying there is no reduce output at all. Just in certain cases I don't want to emit. Like I said, I have a way to deal with this by post-processing but I was just wondering if there is a way to emit or not to emit conditionally. This is doable in Hadoop MapReduce programming paradigm. Also even no reduce at all is doable in Hadoop MapReduce (if map output is what you want).

Comment: @kee I am still confused about the scenario here however the answer is no, if there is no output from the reduce function I believe MongoDBs JS engine will output an error. If you want map output you can just do a simple one liner for it.